# Automate-it app using c for operating systems project

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am doing a project on OS. I am trying similar to AUTOMATE-IT app in android. 
It's an app which automatically dims brightness, turn off WiFi when battery is low etc.

So I am trying something similar in Linux environment. I thought of using C language and thought of implementing the ideas as that app. Like reducing the brightness, turning off WiFi. But i just want to know whether it is possible to carry out in Linux operating system.
Like, are there any system calls or any other way to change the brightness or turn off WiFi using C program . Does Linux allows it?

I tried surfing over the web, but i couldn't get a proper idea, so I thought of asking here.

If it can be carried out, to what extent I can do in Linux ?

Comment: It depends if you are using an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) server or something else like [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29), and which [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) and/or [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) are you using (see [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)...). See also [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acpi).

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing a project on iOS.  And when you say Linux, do you mean Android Linux on a phone or Desktop Linux?